# Добавление картинки в сообщение

Tags: изображения, php, mysql

Подскажите, как можно реализовать, чтобы если пользователь прикрепил к сообщению картинку, то оно показывалось, если нет, то нет. Какова должна быть структура БД и запрос вывода, если оно есть и если его нету, или подкиньте туториал очень хочется разобраться. Подскажите, плз!

Comment: Зачем давать разрешения на вставку картинки? А вдруг пользователь загрузит с хакерских сайтов картинку которая крадет сессии, пароли и т.п

Comment: Имеется ввиду картинка которая загружается с компьютера пользователя а не с стороннего сайта!

Comment: @LovelyCat, сохраняете путь к загруженной картинке в БД вместе с сообщением.

Comment: Ну можно попробовать с помощью php+mysql пользователю будет создаваться альбом туда куда он будет загружать картинки а при загрузке картинки будет добавляться название картинки в бд и кому картинка принадлежит и дать разрешения на вставку bb кода

Answer (score 1):

**Простой вариант**, когда картинка в сообщении может быть только одна — добавить поле `"picture"` в котором хранить локальный адрес картинки, строку `VARCHAR(255)` напр. `"/uploads/2012/trollface.jpg"`. Строка пустая - картинки нет, нечего показывать.

Чуть **сложнее**, если картинкок к одному сообщению может быть и несколько. Понадобится доп. таблица:

```
id    id_сообщения   путь_к_картинке
1     1258           /uploads/2012/08/12/3f5ha2ff.jpg
2     1258           /uploads/2012/08/12/facepalm.jpg
```

Делать придётся два запроса:

1. получать само сообщение;
2. найти к нему по `"id_сообщения"` картинки: вернётся 0, 1 или несколько строк.

Дальше разбираться в PHP — если вернулся пустой список, картинок нет, иначе надо их как-то показывать.

Comment: Не могу не побурчать, sorry :) Структура таблицы 1) потенциально глюкава (не везде можно хранить файлы с китайскими именами; при обработке файлов с не-ascii символами, пробелами и пр. нужны дополнительные усилия и т.д.) 2) избыточна. Проблема 1 и частично 2 решается так: у нас есть первичный ключ, вот пусть он и будет именем файла. Для over 9000 случаев имя значения не имеет, для остальной экзотики можно завести "комментарий" или "оригинальное имя". Избыточность и в том, что хранится путь. Имя храниить нам уже не надо, ergo,  вместо [var]char достаточно простого представления даты :)

Answer (score 0):

.

```
 <?
$uploaddir  = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "File uploading failed.\n";
}
?>
<form name="upload" method="POST"   ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="userfile">
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Загрузить...">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо,меня немного не то интересует само добавление картинки в сообщение пользователя

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так

```
<?php
$asel = mysql_query("select * from `images` where `user`='" . $_SESSION['user'] . "' ORDER BY `id`  DESC") or die("Ошибка!");
while ($arm = mysql_fetch_array($asel)) {
    $text_msg = str_replace("[" . $arm[name] . "]", "<img src=\"/upload/" . $arm[name] . ".png\">", $text_msg);
}
?>
```